Difference between MPPT charger and MPPT boost converter
I am quite confused regarding the MPPT charger and the MPPT boost converter. I have a hybrid inverter where I have a boost converter circuit at the beginning with inputs from the PV. The output of it goes into the battery charging circuit and the AC inverter section. A reference image showing the ON grid part is shown below:

Here I am confused with a few things....suppose my buck voltage was 400V after tracking the maximum power point then it needs a buck converter not a boost converter to make it 310 and then give it to the inverter. Secondly In case of a battery as well how will the system work...will there be another buck converter for the battery?? If there is a buck converter will that also be an MPPT based. If so then which MPPT will work? I mean both taking inputs from the PV if the boost converter output adjusts itself then changing the voltage with a buck wount change the operating point or we have to find a common point for both the converters...???
Kindly help me in understanding these terms...

Your diagram isn't matching your description. For example; "MPPT charger", "MPPT boost converter", and "battery charging circuit" aren't even displayed in your image. You need to delineate what goes where. Also, "suppose my buck voltage was 400V after tracking the maximum power point then it needs a buck converter not a boost converter to make it 310" this is in reference to what?

This is an image to an Ongrid system I gave and I am talking about a hybrid system the
@MOSFET image is just for reference where the boost converter section needs some explaination

Part of the issue is this generic diagram is not representative of your hybrid converter. So I think your making assumptions that may be addressed as part of the design. For example where are you coming up with these voltages? Also, your assuming the inverter section is a buck converter while it most certainly is not. My guess would be transformer based (full-bridge, push-pull, half-bridge, or resonant-mode), all which will handle matching the voltage requirements.
